# Windows Kernel Debugging - Disadvantages to having it on full time?

Tags: windows, kernel, driver, windows-kernel

In the hypothetical world where it is desirable to disable 64 bit Windows Kernel Patch Protection (which is disabled when running in debug mode), **are there any downsides or implications to running a system permanently in debug mode?**

Specifically, is performance meaningfully impacted by this? Or are there any specific limitations that users of a debug system may encounter?

What behaviours, apart from KPP, does the kernel or system as a whole alter if booted with Kernel Mode Debugging enabled? Is the answer different on Windows 7 vs Windows 8/8.1 vs Windows 10?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to disable kernel patch protection!? My spidey sense is tingling...

Comment: There's a reason Microsoft disables it in Debug mode -- simply because it can be exceedingly useful in many legitimate scenarios.

Comment: Maybe this is better asked on RE.SE

Answer (score 1):

The machine can freeze. Some user mode failures get bumped up to kernel breaks.

The DVD software stops working (DRM protection)

Boot time is impacted. (Waiting to attach debugger)

Don't leave it on if you don't need it

Not seen a difference with different os's